# show details of filtered array Xcode 6

Tags: swift, segue, uisearchdisplaycontroller, xcode6gm

i made UIsearch bar to search in my tableview and everything is ok, but the problem when i want to pass data from filtered array to another controller ,after i made the search,
here my prepare

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ahmed" {

           if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {


                print(indexPath.row)

                var object = Persons[indexPath.row]
                (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).name = object.name


    }
    }

}
```

this code work for non searched data which code should i write to pass searched data

Answer (score 0):

i add this code and that works

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ahmed" {

            if((searchDisplayController?.active) != nil)
            {
                if let indexpath=searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                {
                    var object=filtered[indexpath.row]
                    (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).name = object.name


                }
            }
           if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {



                print(indexPath.row)

                var object = Persons[indexPath.row]
                (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).name = object.name


    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the object at Destination view controller and access directly. check below code.

```
//Destination View controller
import UIKit

var marCategoryList : NSMutableArray!

class tsCategoryViewController: UIViewController {

// Source view controller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
    var objTest = tsCategoryViewController() 
    let  marImageNam =  NSMutableArray(objects:"1.jpeg","2.jpeg","3.jpeg","4.jpeg","5.jpeg","6.jpeg","7.jpeg","8.jpeg","9.jpeg","10.jpeg")        
    marCategoryList = marImageNam
    println("\(marCategoryList)")
}
```